# How to add a button to a Standard toolbar of VisualStudio2010 IDE for running add-in using c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Could somebody share a piece of code for adding a new toolbar with custom buttons in it for  VisualStudio2010 IDE for running add-in using c#, please?

Comment: Just create a project type of VS Extensibility Add-in - if you do not have this type then install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question I have found in this brilliant web-site where you can find a lot of answers regarding to building Visual Studio add-ins: [This article provides a code sample to add commands, buttons, commandbars and toolbars to the Visual Studio .NET IDE from an add-in.](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2005/MZ2005003.aspx)